# Почему элементы секции залазят на другую?

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять почему секция features залазит на секцию screenshots? Может быть это из-за того что у каждой section задан отступ сверху и снизу по 120 пикселей, но в других секциях все нормально же отображается

Код jsfiddle.net/z6dhv4gr/
сайт c96180og.beget.tech

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уберите высоту html,body

Comment: но если я это сделаю, то у меня первая секция съедет

Answer (score 1):

Вот некоторые подсказки которые вам помогут найти баги в верстке:

**1) Откройте вашу страницу в обычном браузере, нажмите правой кнопкой мыши и выберите "Просмотреть код" или "Инспектировать элемент"**

У вас откроется справа окно разработчика, в режиме онлайн. Там нажимайте на DIV классы (class) или id которые у вас криво отображаются и вам откроется CSS строка кода которая за это отвечает. Таким образом вы можете **убирать** какие-то пункты **или добавлять прямо в браузере** друг за другом и смотреть что было сделано не так.

Это увеличит скорость поиска ошибки. Такой подход будет сразу вам показывать где вы пропустили пункты, более того большинство браузеров показывают сами сразу где и каких пунктов не хватает в CSS.

**2) При анализе как выглядит ваша верстка на разных устройствах, используйте также специализированные сервисы для этого.**

Простое изменение размера окна браузера на 100% вас подведет и не покажет реальной картины, так было у меня при отображении верстки на Iphone и других Ios устройствах.

Сайт: [www.mobiletest.me](http://www.mobiletest.me) на этом сайте реально происходит эмуляция устройств, а не как в остальных сервисах, псевдо-смена разрешений.

**3) Использование онлайн валидаторов HTML CSS, в которые вы вбиваете ваш код и система автоматически анализирует его и указывает на ошибки.**

Примеры сайтов: [www.freeformatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com)

https://validator.w3.org

На самом деле их сотни, в поисковике найдете тот, который максимально удобен для вас.

**4) Также поэкспериментируйте с разными средами разработки.**

Писать код в обычном текстовом блокноте - это уровень про, но если вы новичок используйте для начала более продвинутые средства разработки наподобие PHP Storm, Code LObster и десятки других где вам сразу показываются ошибки.